# Confluent Kafka Connect can't load my custom connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have installed confluent kafka by following this page : https://serkansakinmaz.medium.com/how-to-install-confluent-on-mac-60b230448312

Post the installation, I am trying to install a custom connector to my local kafka connect via JAR and not able to see all my custom connectors in my local kafka connect.

I have packed my custom connectors module in a JAR and copied it to a "/opt/confluent-5.1.0/share/confluent-hub-components" path. After copying the jar, my plugin.path in connect-distributed.properties was update accordingly.

> plugin.path=/opt/confluent-5.1.0/share/confluent-hub-components

During the startup i could able to see some of my custom connectors getting loaded in my connect logs, however some of the connectors are not getting loaded. Below is my project structure.

src->main->java->com->example->kafkaconnector->

- sink -> HttpSinkConnector (Not loading in connect)
- source -> RabbitMqConnector (Loaded in connect)

Not sure why my HttpSinkConnector is not able to load during the kafka connect startup, however RabbitMqConnector is loading fine.

Once the kafka connect is up and running i could see only the RabbitMqConnector in http://localhost:8083/connector-plugins endpoint

Comment: Are you sure both classes are in the JAR? And both implement the correct Connector interface?

Comment: Yes my HttpSinkConnector extends org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkConnector and RabbitMqConnector extends org.apache.kafka.connect.source.SourceConnector

Comment: Update** -> My HttpSinkConnector extends a common class which extends org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkConnector. Not sure kafka connect supports this type of approach

Comment: Btw, you may want to upgrade Confluent. There's been recent updates to kafka connect plugin loader functions

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, The issue is with the dependencies which is not added in the plugin path location as part of actual jar.

Comment: How did you fix it? Using assembly/shade maven plugin? Or manually adding dependency jars to the plugin path?

Comment: I have added all my project dependencies to the same path. Now my plugin path location is having an actual connector classes jar + dependencies

Comment: The maven assembly plugin for example can package that all into one JAR. There is also a kafka-connect-maven-plugin that creates a ZIP you can unextract to the plugin path

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).